# Changing values of indexes by magnitude

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a flexible algorithm that will take values out of a 50 by 50 array (which contains pixel values from a fits image) if they are too high. 
they are too high (in python). The first thing I tried to do was this:

```
file = pf.open('/Users/Vofun/desktop/file.fits')
data = np.array(file[0].data)
for pixellist in range (len(data)):
        if data[pixellist] > 50:
           data[pixellist] = 10:
```

of course, that didn't work, and I got

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

the problem is, if I do that, I have no idea how to tell it which value to replace if I use a.any(). So far I think what I'll need is:

```
if a.any(data) > 50:
```

and then a line of code telling it to replace the value with ten, but I'm not sure how to tell it to do that for the pixel it found, because I'm kind of terrible at coding. How would I reduce the value of the indexes based on if their value exceeds 50?

Comment: What is the [shape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape) of ```data```?

Comment: I knew I should have included that. It's 50 by 50

Comment: I don't understand what `sec_data` is it also a 50 by 50?

Comment: oops…  I changed half of the names in this to generic names and left the other half with the original names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to change your data.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random_integers(40, 60, (5,5))

>>> a
array([[58, 58, 43, 56, 54],
       [59, 40, 42, 52, 45],
       [50, 60, 43, 48, 52],
       [55, 48, 57, 41, 47],
       [57, 55, 43, 54, 42]])
>>>
>>> a > 50
array([[ True,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
>>>
>>> a[a > 50] = 0
>>> a
array([[42,  0,  0,  0, 48],
       [ 0, 46,  0,  0, 49],
       [50,  0,  0, 44, 43],
       [46, 46,  0, 43, 49],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 48]])
>>>
```

Comment: okay, so if I go 'data[data > 50] = 0' it will assign the value 0 to all indexes within data with values greater than 50. but what do the first two arrays have to do with the third one? The third one is the only one that really seems to do anything. Why use the booleans at all? The third array has nothing to d with the booleans...

Comment: @Vofun, I really don't understand what you are asking in the comment - did you read the link for boolean indexing?  In my answer I first showed the array being operated on, then I showed the result of a comparison expression on that array so you could see that it creates a boolean array of the same shape, then I showed how you could selectively change array elements using boolean indexing.